# 'Error: Cannot write configuration file' is not getting resolved even with admin access

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

Whenever I try to load a solution in Visual Studio Community 2015, I  get the following error message (even with admin rights). I tried to rename the `applicationhost.config` file (as some solution suggested), but it did not solve the problem.

[image: Error message]

Comment: The path look wrong what is: `\\?\` in the begining?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten It's not wrong. \\?\ is a way to define a long pathname.

Comment: Did you try to delete the `.vs` folder ?

Comment: Maybe the applicationhost.config file is read-only (e.g. because of source control).

Comment: Do you run  it under IIS or under IIS-Express?  Either way, make sure your site is stopped. Close VS and check that `localhost:48199` does _not_ respond in your browser.

Comment: @gobes Yes, I tried. Still no luck!

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider No, it is Writable!

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I tried. It is not responding. So, I guess the port is not occupied.

Comment: When in doubt, reboot. Did you try to reboot your computer ? some process can have a lock on the file.